# Create an Merge Request during the pipeline in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

When will run the MR merging the “test” feature branch into the release branch.The pipeline will trigger and Create an MR to merge the “test” feature branch into the develop branch in Gitlab CI(using bash script).Can anyone help me with how to do that?